# How I can get map on JSP page age and show the key and value in two columns of a table

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have generated a map on my controller.

```
  Map<String, String> currentbatchitems = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentbatchitem.size(); i++) {
        currentbatchitems.put(currentbatchitem.get(i).getEmpCode(), currentbatchitem.get(i).getEmpName().toString());

    }
    data.put("currentbatchitems", currentbatchitems);
```

How can I show the the key and value in separate column on my JSP. Such as,[This the table.The key of the map is employee code and value is employee name.How could I add the row on this table by getting the value from this map?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI7Md.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your Map by adding Employee instances to it rather than simply the name.

```
Map<String, Employee> currentBatchitems = new HashMap<String, Employee>();

for (Employee employee : currentbatchitem) {
    currentbatchitems.put(employee.getEmpCode(), employee);

}

data.put("currentbatchitems", currentbatchitems);
```

Using the JSTL Core tag lib you can iterate the map and then use JSP EL to write the values:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${currentbatchitems}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${entry.key}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${entry.value.empName}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${entry.value.salary}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</html>
```